# Solving an infinite system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations

I'm hoping to solve the system of equations
$$ a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + a_4 + ... = A_1$$
$$ a_1 + 2a_2 + 4a_3 + 8a_4 + ... = A_2$$
$$ a_1 + 3a_2 + 9a_3 + 27a_4 + ... = A_3$$
$$ ...$$
$$ a_1 + n^1a_2 + n^2a_3 + n^3a_4 + ... A_n$$
Here, all $A_n$ are known, and there are countably infinitely many $A_n$ given. My hope is to be able to compute alternating versions of the original sums in terms of $A_1$ through $A_n$.
So, I'd like to compute
$$ a_1 - a_2 + a_3 - a_4 + ... = ??$$
$$ a_1 - 2a_2 + 4a_3 - 8a_4 + ... = ??$$
etc.

I've tried looking at this as a matrix, but I'm unsure of how to invert an infinitely large matrix. Any help would be appreciated!

Edit: As the comments mentioned, the question posed doesn't have a unique solution. Instead, I'd like to look at assigning a unique value by looking at the limit of solutions of n x n matrices. For instance, I can notice a few patterns when looking at the solutions of smaller. For instance for the first two, the top and bottom lines seem to have a pattern. The top lines are values of Pascal's triangle with some sign changes. The bottom lines appear to be 1/factorials with sign changes.
[image]
These patterns seem to keep for larger matricies[image]
Is there a nice solution for an arbitrarily large nxn matrix?

Comment: Perhaps I am wrong, but I think there should exist $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $a_n=0$ for all $n\geqslant n_0$. Consequently, there are two possibilities: 1) your system does not have any solution; 2) your system is equivalent to the first $n_0$ equations and you only need to solve them with the first $n_0$ unknown quantities $a_1$, $a_2$, ..., $a_{n_0}$.

Comment: Consider the function $f(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_{k+1}z^k$. The system tells you that this function is analytic on $|z|<n$ and that $f(k)=A_k$, for $k=1,2,3,...,n$. You can construct such function using Weierstrass and Mittag-Leffler's theorems. The function is not unique. You can add any function that has zeros at $1,2,3,...,n$ and analytic on $|z|<n$. Then the values that you seek are $f(−1),f(−2),f(−3),...$ Up to which $f(-k)$ do you need?

Comment: @plop I'm hoping to get all values of f(-k), so for all positive integers. I can see how solutions for $A_n=0$ could cause solutions to not be unique (for instance adding the Taylor series for $\frac{\sin(\pi(x+1))}{(x+1)}$ doesn't affect $A_n$ for positive but it does affect for negative values). At the same time, it also seems like there should be a natural way to assign a unique value since this is an n x n matrix of linearly independent vectors. Is there a way to get a unique value possibly by taking the limit of solutions for n x n sub matrices or something similar?

Comment: You may find the Wikipedia article [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix) helpful.